# Capturing multiple values for single argument in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script like this :

```
usage="setup.sh [-localsource path to dir] [-help]";

 for i in $@
    do
        if [ "$localSourceOpt" = 1 ]
        then
            localSource=$i
            localSourceOpt=0;
        fi
        if [ "$i" = "-localsource" ]
        then
            localSourceOpt=1;
        fi
        if [ "$i" = "-help" ]
        then
            echo "$usage";
            exit;
        fi
    done
```

which requires on argument e.g

```
setup.sh -localsource PATH
```

what I need is to add another argument which MIGHT have multiple argument values e.g

```
 setup.sh -localsource PATH  -locbranches one two three
```

What I should do to capture  values passed for argument  "-locbranches"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I note that you're having to code a lot of logic to handle the simplest command-line argument mechanism, and I'd perhaps suggest using the `bash` [getopts functionality](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) instead.

This makes the single argument option work trivial. For multiple arguments it doesn't work well, and you would have to quote the args e.g. `-option "1 2 3"`. However it *does* handle multiple arguments in the following scenario.

```
setup.sh -localsource PATH one two three
```

i.e. the `one two three` aren't linked to any command line option. An alternative is to specify the option for each argument e.g.

```
setup.sh -localsource PATH -locbranch one -locbranch two -locbranch three
```

Comment: `setup.sh -localsource PATH -locbranch one -locbranch two -locbranch three` seems possibly simple way to go

Comment: Yes. I think it's simple and intuitive

Answer (score 0):

You can do a switch with 4 cases ( -localsource , -locbranches, -help and default) and in each case you should enter in one state,

```
for i in $@; do
  case "$i" in

   "-help") echo "$usage"
            ;;
   "-localsource") STATE="localsource"
                 ;;
   "-locbranches") STATE="locbranches"
                 ;;
   *) 
          if [ "$STATE" == "localsource" ]; then
             PATH=$i
          elif [ "$STATE" == "locbranches"]; then
             # do something with argv from locbrances
          else
             echo "Wrong state!"
          fi
          ;;
  esac
done
```